# Groovy version downgrade 2.2.1

Tags: groovy

We have been building our application using groovy 2.3.6. Now because of some platform level issues we are advised to downgrade our groovy version to 2.2.1. I am facing no. of issues regarding this downgrade.

groovy is not able to infer the type of it variable in ver 2.2.1 so if i have code something like this

```
names.any { sliceName.endsWith(it) }
```

it gives me exception

```
[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.String#endsWith(java.lang.Object)
```

Secondly all the default method that i had used in collections no longer seem to exist

```
positions.any { it.primary }
```

groovy is unable to find the any method on list.

One way would be turn off static type checking, which will expose the code to a lot more runtime errors.

Is there any way to resolve these errors, without turning off static type checking. Also are these features only added in groovy 2.3.6 like default groovy methods and type inference for it variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go back to an old version, old bugs will bite you.

Try giving the static compiler more of a hint

```
names.any { String it -> sliceName.endsWith(it) }
```